# What are some easy papers in mathematics understood by undergraduates?

Tags: soft-question, advice

Being a junior(3rd.year) undergraduate in mathematics, I would like to learn how serious papers of mathematics do the proofs rigorously as opposed to textbooks and proffessors in lectures and I wish to see this by myself. For this reason , I just want to read at least one paper which I can understand the topic and proofs.

Though the aim of this reading process is to learn the extent of rigorousness in papers , I want also the subject to interest me so that I would learn something. That is why I might choose the topics somewhat related to real analysis since I consider doing Phd on real& functional analysis  or probability & stochastic analysis.Hence, subjects could be Real Analysis, Game Theory, Probability or Stochastic Processes.

The thing is that I should be able to understand the paper to avoid throwing the paper away. I am at the level of Apostol's Mathematical Analysis(Point set topology ,metric spaces, differentiation &integration, continuity, uniform convergence, series and sequences of functions etc.) and I took a course on Lebesgue Integration which started Lebesgue Theory by sequence of step functions. I have not taken or read any thing on Stochastic Calculus but I know Applied Probability and Statistics at the  level ,say undergraduate engineering student.

With all these in mind, which spesific paper do you suggest me to read?

EDIT based on comments:

1) The paper that I am looking for can be any theorem which is usually a subject of an undergraduate real analysis courses or from a textbook on real analysis. To give some examples, Fubini's Theorem, Beppo-Levi's Theorem in Lebesgue Integration or Banach's Fixed Point Theorem, Arzela-Ascoli Theorem, Baire Theorem etc. on Analysis can be candidates .

Comment: This is such a broad topic which clearly has the tendency on getting "down-votes." (I hope not) So what's your field of interest, Mathematical Analysis ?

Comment: the paper I am looking for can be on any theorem which is a subject of undergraduate mathematical analysis courses. For example Fubini's Theorem on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Right. Couple of ways on top of my head. Check "Google Scholar" option and search on the topic of your interest. Also, go to https://arxiv.org/, choose Mathematics and do the same.

Comment: If I do that  It can go very broad set of papers which I might choose one that I migh not able to understand  even a single line of the paper at all. That is why I am looking an answer here.

Comment: It's not an easy process considering the level you're at. Either you asked some papers from an instructor who knows your level of understanding. Or you do it by yourself. It's up to you. Initially it'll be hard. But you'll get use to it.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but this might be a very difficult task. While the proofs in mathematical papers are usually rigorous, they are typically very short. If someone has done mathematics for a long time, these steps will be easy to fill - but possibly not by someone who is still learning mathematics. Also, most modern papers heavily rely on previous work and are very complicated to read. Maybe you should look into the proofs for the irrationality of $\pi$ and $e$, like here https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510788

Comment: Most papers are referencing many other papers and are difficult to read for this reason, while in books, everything has been put together. That's the only difference.

Comment: The theorems you mention are mostly quite old. As such, the papers where they were proved will not give you much idea of what proofs look like in papers now.

Comment: At what level does reading papers start to make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestions:**

- *[Taking Limits Under the Integral Sign](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/FCunninghamJr.pdf)* by F. Cunningham Jr.

Source: Mathematics Magazine, vol. 40, 1967, pp. 179-186.

- *[Arzela's Dominated Convergence Theorem for the Riemann Integral](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_15/dominated.pdf)* by W. A. J. Luxemburg.

Source: The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 78, No. 9 (Nov., 1971), pp. 970-979.

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly look deeper into your suggestion @Pedro and I am open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: arzela has many generalisations

Answer (score 2):

Another Suggestion:

[A simple proof that $\pi$ is irrational](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788)

It is a one page proof. It is not a proof of a major theorem, and questionably fits into your field though.

Comment: It is a one page but, in my opinion, in order to make it readable for an undergraduate student we have to expand it considerably, as done [in this series](https://mathlesstraveled.com/?s=Irrationality+of+pi) (or [in this text](http://manthanos.blogspot.com.br/2012/12/uma-prova-de-que-e-irracional_20.html) in portuguese).